# Why am I able to initialize a const in constructor?

Tags: c++

As the title suggests, I've always thought of constants values to be set and cannot be modified however I've noticed you are able to change it in the constructor. As you can see I created a string name which is later to be set as whatever I pass through the constructor, why is this allow?

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class test{
    const string name;
public:
    test(const string &nam) : name(nam) {}

    string get_name() { return name; }
};

int main ()
{
    test a("Tom");
    cout << a.get_name();

   // const string t1;
  //  string t2 = "changing"; this causes an error
  //  t1 = &t2;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not changing it, you are initializing it. If you couldn't do this, const members would be kind of useless...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't changing the `const string`. You're initializing it.

`const` means that once the variable has been initialized, it cannot be changed. It does not mean `constexpr` (which means a compile-time constant expression).

`const` values can be set at run time. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;

    const int y = x; // This is totally fine.
    std::cout << "You entered the number " << y;
}
```

In the above example, the value of `y` is determined at runtime (after reading the value `x`). It is initialized with the value of `x`, and after it has been initialized, we can't change its value.*

It's the exact same with a `const` member.

*Changing* a variable implies that it exists, has a value, and then you set it to a new value. That's not the case here. The variable/member does not exist until the constructor is called. Since it does not exist, it cannot possibly have some previous value. Instead, you're creating the variable/member and giving it its (first and only) value, all at the same time (which is what we mean when we talk about *initialization*). There is no *change* in that process.

<sup>*`const_cast` lets us change the value of a `const` reference to a variable that isn't originally `const`. So workarounds exist. But if the original variable (not just the reference) is `const` you'll invoke undefined behavior if you modify it. Thankfully you have to go out of your way to do this, so if you do it's probably not an accident.</sup>

Comment: I thought upon creation of the string eg "const string name" is where it would be initialized if that is not the case, shouldn't commented out code compile since I haven't initialized anything to it yet?

Comment: @Wolf: But it's a class member, not a variable. It doesn't exist until you create instance of that class (call a constructor). So it makes sense to initialize const member in a constructor. If you want const member that is the same for all instances of the same class, that's what `static` keyword is for.

Comment: @Wolf: Indeed, as Jaa-c said, the `name` variable is not created until you create an instance of the `test` class, which is what you do when you create and construct that `a` object in your code. The commented out code is different because it actually *has* been initialized already. `t1` is initialized in that first line because its default constructor is run (which results in the empty string).